# SuperNotCalledException: Activity CropImage did not call through to super.onConfigurationChanged()

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using ACTIVITY and initialized as PORTRAIT in Android manifest. so i didn't use onConfigurationChanged() method in that Activity. But Still getting this error.

I Initialized as Portrait in AndroidManifest as follows :

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
</activity>
```

Print Stack Trace :

```
android.util.SuperNotCalledException: Activity CropImage did not call through to super.onConfigurationChanged()
```

--------- Stack trace ---------

```
    android.app.ActivityThread.performConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:5575) 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleActivityConfigurationChanged(ActivityThread.java:5908) 

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7270) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:
1230) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Can you post some of your activity code, atleast lifecycle methods

Comment: Yes, OnCreate, OnBackPressed, OnPause, OnDestroy, OnResume.

Comment: and i initialized as portrait in AndroiManifest as follows                    <activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
</activity>

Comment: Post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Well your logs tell you everything you need to know to solve the problem. **Activity CropImage did not call through to super.onConfigurationChanged()** I assume in your Activity `CropImage` you are `Overriding` method `onConfigurationChanged()`. All you need to do is call `super.onConfigurationChanged()`, like so:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    // Do something here.
    .
    .
    .
    // But don't forget to call this method
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i didn't use onConfigurationChanged method, instead of that i am initialized in Manifest file as Portrait,  <activity
        android:name=".CropImage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    </activity>  .... Do you think still i need to use OnConfigurationChanged()

Comment: No you don't need to. Since we can only guess looking at the given information why don't you [Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces this issue.

Comment: But myself i can't reproduce this issue. but only some users are getting this issue

Comment: Yes I just checked, seems to me every one had changed orientation at run time. why don't you Try this on a different device.